# !Syntax Error: on line 3: expected one of @import *-@:.#

Tags: less

I want to import some vars and mixings from a less file located under a subdirectory.

I´m using the following code:

```
@import "./subdirectory/file.less"
```

I have tried:

```
@import "subdirectory/file.less"
```

But the compiler shows the following error:

```
!Syntax Error: on line 3: expected one of @import *-@:.#
```

Comment: @import "partner/unimar/event_detail.less"; seems to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@import "/subdirectory/file.less";`

You seem to be missing the semi-colon?

Comment: Yes, you have to include the absolute path from the path directory and the semi-colon